# SVN to GIT migration - can we ignore git-svn-id in Migrated commit messages

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn

I have migrated  one repository from svn to Git using git-svn tool. After migration, commits history include SVN mapping information as part of the commit messages. Would it be possible to exclude the git-svn-id info in the messages of migrated commits?

Commit message coming after migration -
git-svn-id: https://svn-url/svn/repo-name/@163121 c3204716-b836-0410-8dec-96a83ff3a94f

We need only this part in commit message "163121 c3204716-b836-0410-8dec-96a83ff3a94f" As git-svn-id: https://svn-url/svn/repo-name/@ is added by git-svn tool while converting the repository.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is surely possible to rewrite the entire history to modify the commit message but it will be complicated to do (especially for a git beginner) and it doesn't worth it (and you also keep some not hurting information). So, I would say, keep it and move on...

Comment: Commit message coming after migration - git-svn-id: https://svn-url/svn/repo-name//trunk@163121 c3204716-b836-0410-8dec-96a83ff3a94f

We need only this part in commit message "163121 c3204716-b836-0410-8dec-96a83ff3a94f" As git-svn-id: https://svn-url/svn/repo-name/trunk@ is added by git-svn tool while converting the repository.

Comment: Added an answer...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git filter-branch` to update all the commit messages using a command looking like this one (regex not tested):

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter "sed 's/^ git-svn-id: [^ ]+ //g'" -- --all
```

Then verify that all is ok and delete the folder `.git/refs/original` ( to delete old branches) and force push all the branches.

But that will modify all the commits sha1.

But as I said in a comment on the question, it's a long and tedious task and I don't think it worth the burden just to remove some string that won't annoy you...